# How to fail service so that SERVICE_RESULT contains "start-limit-hit"

Tags: linux, systemd, services

So, I have a systemd service which executes a script in ExecStopPost:

```
[Unit]
Description=foobar-test
StartLimitBurst=3
StartLimitIntervalSec=120

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/do_something.sh
ExecStopPost=/handle_stop.sh $SERVICE_RESULT
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1

[Install]
...
```

Script "do_something.sh" just exits with return code 1 so that service just keeps restarting on-failure until start limit is hit.

Script "handle_stop.sh" just prints out content of $SERVICE_RESULT

When service hits start limit the content of $SERVICE_RESULT is "exit-code" instead of "start-limit-hit" as I expected it to be according to [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#%24SERVICE_RESULT)

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in systemd?

systemd version: systemd 244 (244.5+)
+PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR -SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP -LIBCRYPTSETUP -GCRYPT -GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID -ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 -IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`man 5 systemd.exec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#%24SERVICE_RESULT) says:

> "start-limit-hit":    A start limit was defined for the unit and it was hit, causing the unit to fail to start.

[`man 5 systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#StartLimitIntervalSec=interval) says:

> Note that units which are configured for Restart=, and which reach the start limit are not attempted to be restarted anymore; however, they may still be restarted manually or from a timer or socket at a later point, after the interval has passed.

You could argue that `systemd` is behaving per documentation.  `start-limit-hit` only happens if a unit fails to start.  But `Restart=` will not attempt to (re)start a unit that has already been started `StartLimitBurst=` times within `StartLimitIntervalSec=`.

But I did spend some effort trying to get that method to appear.

First I tried to trigger the burst, then try another `systemctl start` to manually start it.  The hypothesis was that the unit never started after reaching start-limit-hit because systemd will not restart units that are past that limit.  If true, in this experiment, the unit would fail to start when explicitly commanded to do so and give the desired code.

```
$ systemctl --user cat startlimit.service 
# ~/.config/systemd/user/startlimit.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/false
Restart=always
StartLimitIntervalSec=20

$ systemctl --user start startlimit.service
$ systemctl --user start startlimit.service
Job for startlimit.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl --user status startlimit.service" and "journalctl --user -xeu startlimit.service" for details.

$ systemctl --user status startlimit.service
× startlimit.service
     Loaded: loaded (/home/stew/.config/systemd/user/startlimit.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-10-24 18:10:11 CEST; 5s ago
   Duration: 1ms
    Process: 5008 ExecStart=/bin/false (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 5008 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 1ms

Oct 24 18:10:11 systemd[1129]: startlimit.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 24 18:10:11 systemd[1129]: Stopped startlimit.service.
Oct 24 18:10:11 systemd[1129]: startlimit.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 24 18:10:11 systemd[1129]: startlimit.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 24 18:10:11 systemd[1129]: Failed to start startlimit.service.
Oct 24 18:10:12 systemd[1129]: startlimit.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 24 18:10:12 systemd[1129]: startlimit.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 24 18:10:12 systemd[1129]: Failed to start startlimit.service.
```

The hypthesis was proved to be false.

The next guess was "maybe systemctl will refuse to start units that are passed that limit".  "Maybe it's something systemd needs to trigger itself".  To do that, I created another one-shot dummy service which `Wants=` the service above.    Then I triggered it several times.

```
$ systemctl --user cat startlimit{,Wanter.service}
# ~/.config/systemd/user/startlimit.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/false
Restart=always
StartLimitIntervalSec=20

[Install]
WantedBy=startlimitWanter.service

# ~/.config/systemd/user/startlimitWanter.service
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true

$ systemctl --user start startlimitWanter.service
$ systemctl --user start startlimitWanter.service
$ systemctl --user start startlimitWanter.service
$ systemctl --user status startlimit{,Wanter.service}
× startlimit.service
     Loaded: loaded (~/.config/systemd/user/startlimit.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-10-24 18:13:49 CEST; 7s ago
   Duration: 1ms
    Process: 5066 ExecStart=/bin/false (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 5066 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 1ms


Oct 24 18:13:50 systemd[1129]: Failed to start startlimit.service.
Oct 24 18:13:52 systemd[1129]: startlimit.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 24 18:13:52 systemd[1129]: startlimit.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 24 18:13:52 systemd[1129]: Failed to start startlimit.service.

○ startlimitWanter.service
     Loaded: loaded (~/.config/systemd/user/startlimitWanter.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Oct 24 18:13:48 systemd[1129]: Starting startlimitWanter.service...
Oct 24 18:13:48 systemd[1129]: Finished startlimitWanter.service.
Oct 24 18:13:50 systemd[1129]: Starting startlimitWanter.service...
Oct 24 18:13:50 systemd[1129]: Finished startlimitWanter.service.
Oct 24 18:13:52 systemd[1129]: Starting startlimitWanter.service...
Oct 24 18:13:52 systemd[1129]: Finished startlimitWanter.service.
```

That one also failed to get your message.

At this point I'm inclined to agree that you've stumbled on a bug.

Comment: Thought so, thanks for effort, I'll report this to systemd github